# Explosion of memory usage when fitting a RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to fit a Forest with a medium-sized array of numpy floats

```
In [3]: data.shape
Out[3]: (401125, 5)

[...]
forest = forest.fit(data[:,1:],data[:,0])
```

The issue occurs something like 10 seconds after the fitting is initiated. It takes up to 3.6 GB (of 3.8 GB) of memory before it freezes my machine and I have to kill the process.

I've been researching, and this issue seems to be pretty common when you set `n_jobs` to something bigger than 1. But I'm using the default value for n_jobs, namely, 1.

I've also try to change `n_estimators` from my initial value, 100, to 5, just to see if something different happens but everything stays the same.

Could anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to convert your data to a Fortran aligned float32 array?

Comment: You mean using [numpy.asfortranarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asfortranarray.html)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is the memory layout used by the random forest models internally.

Comment: @ogrisel Oops this is embarrassing. I was actually trying to make a regression, not a classification. I have now change the class for the Random Forest, and there is no enormous amount of memory being used. (Although it takes a great amount of time) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Interesting, I had not thought about that possibility. Maybe we should raise a warning if the target variable has a float dtype.

Comment: Everything worked fine. I have work before with RandomForestClassifier using a float dtype array, and it also work fine. But that warning wouldn't be a mad thing at all.
In this particular case, being a Classifier, it tried to make a fit with over 400000 'labels' before I realize I wanted to make a regression. Maybe that's the reason of the ridiculous memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. I was actually trying to make a regression, not a classification.
Closing question.